# Problem with executing command when a player reaches a certain amount of score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to execute a command when a player's `kills` score reaches a certain value, but it doesn't work.

[image]

This image should explain it all.

How do I execute a command when the player reaches a certain amount of score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your command.

First of all, your target selector is wrong. [Target selector arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) use a `<argument>=<value>` syntax, meaning it should be `score_kills_min=1`. A colon as separator is only used for data tags (which you aren't using in this command).

Secondly, the syntax for [`execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) requires 4 arguments before the other command:

```
execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> <command …>
```

Minecraft commands are *dumb*, they can not divine which arguments are not given when some are missing. In your case, the game sees the following arguments:

```
<entity> = @p[score_kills_min=1]
<x> = setblock
<y> = 195 
<z> = 56 
<command …> = -1199 minecraft:redstone_block
```

This is obviously rubbish and the command would fail. If you don't require `<command …>` to be run from a specific location (if you do, you *know*), just use `~ ~ ~` for the coordinates.

In summary, your command should be:

```
execute @p[score_kills_min=1] ~ ~ ~ setblock 195 56 -1199 minecraft:redstone_block
```